# utf8_encode and hypens

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, json

In my php file:

```
foreach ($output[0] as $key => $value){
    $output[0][$key] = utf8_encode(strip_tags($output[0][$key]));       
}
echo (json_encode($output));
```

I was encoding in utf8 to avoid getting `null` when a character with umlaut gets in the way, then I found an hyphen, this is the text I'm getting form output:

```
H\u00f6rbuch-CDs
```

Then when doing json_encode I get `null`. The original text was `Hörbuch-CDs` so basically the utf8 encoding is working but for some reason it skips the hyphens, I even [found](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html) the code (I think) for utf conversion that should be `U+002D`, I'm not sure because there are tons of hyphens like symbol, meaning that a conversion exists.

My questions are, why is utf8_encoding not... encoding? How can I resolve this issue? Should I parse the text and manually substitute every hyphen?

Little extra, the text in output is retrieved form a database with collation `latin1_german1_ci`, don't know it this can be helpful.

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but you should have a look at the array_map() function to avoid using foreach() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: The hyphen is totally legal in UTF-8 so no problem there. But you are only encoding `$output[0]` -- what about the rest of it?

Comment: @ mimipc thanks totally forgot about array_map()s function.
@Jon $output is an array of array with a single array in it, so with $output[0] I'm referencing the only array in it, I know it's not elegant, I was just making an example to post a question on SO. Also, i thought about that too, that hyphens are legal caracthers in utf8, but there's a code for conversion for a reason i think.

Comment: It might be useful to see an example of your full json_encode output (as it is echo'd)

Comment: @niaccurshi This is the $output:  `["products_name"]=> H\u00f6rbuch-CDs`
and this is the echo: `"products_name":null`

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled on your server? I would expect something like `json_encode() [function.json-encode]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument`

Comment: @Jon You were right about the hyphens legality and the array indexing with [0], my stupid mistake, if you want to post that as answer I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: @EndeNeu: No need, IMHO better to close as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using iconv instead of utf8_encode?

```
iconv('LATIN1','UTF-8',strip_tags($output[0][$key]));
```

Comment: Still getting `null`.

Comment: `utf8_encode` is documented to do exactly this, so what's the point?

Comment: Also I'm getting `null` to characters with umlaut.